# IllegalArgumentException with Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, itext

Here is a small Test code that sets the background to an itext chunk object. what i intend to do is execute following method on chunk object using reflection 
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(); BaseColor baseColor = new BaseColor(45,90,135); chunk.setBackground(baseColor);

```
package com.blubench.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;

public class BaseColorReflection {

    static final String methodName = "setBackground";
    static final String className = "com.itextpdf.text.Chunk";
    static final String param = "com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        //**********Target Class**************
        Class<?> chunkClass = Class.forName(className);
        Chunk chunk = (Chunk) chunkClass.newInstance();

        //*********Parameter to Target Method*********
        Class<?> baseColorClass = Class.forName(param);     
        Class<?>[] argTypes = {int.class,int.class,int.class};
        Constructor<?> baseColorCtor = baseColorClass.getDeclaredConstructor(argTypes);     
        Object[] argValues = {45,90,135};
        Object baseColorObject = baseColorCtor.newInstance(argValues);

        //*********Target Method****************
        Method method = chunkClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName,baseColorObject.getClass());

        try {

            //***********Invoke Target Method on Target Class with Parameter**********
            method.invoke(chunk, baseColorObject.getClass());

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   

}
```

This is what i get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.blubench.test.BaseColorReflection.main(BaseColorReflection.java:33)

This is a very common problem but i am unable to identify what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the parameter instance, not the class of the parameter:

Change

```
method.invoke(chunk, baseColorObject.getClass());
```

To

```
method.invoke(chunk, baseColorObject);
```